# Select equivalent in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In my app, I'm using MySQL and what I want to do is to get the equivalent of a certain grade.
        Like for example, I have a grade of 13, the equivalent of it is 5.0.

I have this type of table structure with data.

```
    `transmutation` table

    id      grade   equi
    1       0       5.0
    2       14      4.0
```

And it also come to my mind that I could do this.

```
    `transmutation` table

    id      grade       equi
    1       01-13       5.0
    2       14-26       4.0
```

For now, I have this simple syntax in getting equivalent and it's incomplete.

```
    SELECT equi from transmutation WHERE grade BETWEEN 0 AND 14 AND grade = 0;
```

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Comment: Your second example can work, just separate the `grade` field into 2 fields -- `grade_start` and `grade_end`.  Then you can easily use `between` to get your desired results.

Comment: This helped me a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be to define your table like this:

`transmutation` table

```
id      gradeFrom   gradeTo  equi
1       0           13       5.0
2       14          26       4.0
```

And then:

```
SELECT equi FROM transmutation WHERE 13 BETWEEN gradeFrom and gradeTo
```

Comment: This will do! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Well, `BETWEEN` will not work in this scenario but if you have your table data in second format per post then you can do a simple `=` equality comparison like
below provided that the `grade` column data format is same

```
SELECT equi from transmutation WHERE grade = '01-13';
```

Answer (score 3):

I feel the conceptually easiest way to handle this is to store the *ranges* for the grades in a table, and map each range to an equivalent value like this:

```
transmutation
+----+------------+----------+------+
| id | gradeStart | gradeEnd | equi |
+----+------------+----------+------+
| 1  |     1      |    13    | 5.0  |
| 2  |     14     |    26    | 4.0  |
+----+------------+----------+------+
```

Then, given a grade number, you can map it to an equivalent value using a query of this sort:

```
SELECT equi
FROM transmutation
WHERE someGrade >= gradeStart AND someGrade <= gradeEnd
```

Comment: This works fine! Thanks! Now I just need to modify my table